# For all natural numbers $n$, if $n$ is odd, then $\sqrt{15^n}$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

How can I show that for all natural numbers $n$, if $n$ is odd, then $\sqrt{15^n}$ is irrational? I have tried to use a proof by contradiction to no avail. I have gotten decently far with a proof by contraposition, where I assume that $\sqrt{15^n}$ is rational and prove that $n$ is even.

For integers $x$ and $y$:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{15^n} &= \frac{x}{y} \\
15^n &= \frac{x^2}{y^2} \\
15 &= \frac{x^{\frac{2}{n}}}{y^{\frac{2}{n}}}
\end{align*}

From here, I don't know how I would isolate the $n$ to prove that it is even. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are allowed to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, try it.

Comment: Let $n=2k+1$.  You have $\sqrt{15^{n}}=\sqrt{15^{2k+1}}=15^k\cdot \sqrt{15}$.  Show that $\sqrt{15}$ is irrational, $15^k$ is rational and nonzero, and recall that an irrational number times a rational nonzero number is necessarily irrational.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, the other posters used that same logic. That works well, I should have thought of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by saying that if $n$ is the odd natural numbers then it can be represented as:
$$n=2k+1\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0$$

---

Secondly,
$$15=5\cdot3\rightarrow \sqrt{15^n}=5^{n/2}3^{n/2}$$

---

now substitute in our form for $n$ and we get:
$$5^k3^k\sqrt{5}\sqrt{3}$$
or:
$$15^k\sqrt{15}$$
then we know that:
$$15^k\in\mathbb{Q}\forall k,\sqrt{15}\notin \mathbb{Q}$$
and so:
$$15^k\sqrt{15}\notin\mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: Gotcha, this makes a lot of sense. I didn't think about using the fact that an irrational times a rational is irrational, but it works perfectly here. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
\sqrt{15^n} = 15^{(2k+1)/2} = 15^k \sqrt{15}. 
$$
So if $\sqrt{15^n} \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\sqrt{15} \in \mathbb{Q}$, as well. Can you show $\sqrt{15}$ is irrational?

Comment: Yes, I think I've got it now. Thank you!